# PHP Strange code behaviour

Tags: php, curl, url-shortener, goo.gl

Here is my goo.gl url shortener class. Using it like Googl::shorten("http://google.com"). I can't understand why it returns Null. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
define('GOOGLE_API_KEY', 'AIzaSyBS7WpEDiSZ91p-SJoNWOkKxqveb1sfpf4');
define('GOOGLE_ENDPOINT', 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1');
class Googl {

  static function shorten($longUrl)
    {
        // initialize the cURL connection
        $ch = curl_init(
            sprintf('%s/url?key=%s', GOOGLE_ENDPOINT, GOOGLE_API_KEY)
        );

        // tell cURL to return the data rather than outputting it
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        // create the data to be encoded into JSON
        $requestData = array(
            'longUrl' => $longUrl
        );

        // change the request type to POST
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

        // set the form content type for JSON data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));

        // set the post body to encoded JSON data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($requestData));

        // perform the request
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        // decode and return the JSON response
        return json_decode($result, true);
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this param.. (*Since googleapis run on HTTPs*)

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

and call like

```
$res= Googl::shorten('http://stackoverflow.com');
var_dump($res);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
array (size=3)
  'kind' => string 'urlshortener#url' (length=16)
  'id' => string 'http://goo.gl/Vmnf' (length=18)
  'longUrl' => string 'http://stackoverflow.com/' (length=25)
```

---

#### The whole code..

```
<?php
define('GOOGLE_API_KEY', 'AIzaSyBS7WpEDiSZ91p-SJoNWOkKxqveb1sfpf4');
define('GOOGLE_ENDPOINT', 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1');
class Googl {

    static function shorten($longUrl)
    {
        // initialize the cURL connection
        $ch = curl_init(
            sprintf('%s/url?key=%s', GOOGLE_ENDPOINT, GOOGLE_API_KEY)
        );

        // tell cURL to return the data rather than outputting it
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        // create the data to be encoded into JSON
        $requestData = array(
            'longUrl' => $longUrl
        );

        // change the request type to POST
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

        // set the form content type for JSON data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        // set the post body to encoded JSON data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($requestData));

        // perform the request
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        // decode and return the JSON response
        return json_decode($result, true);
    }

}
$res= Googl::shorten('http://stackoverflow.com');
var_dump($res);
```

Comment: Tried. Same thing. Null. Can you please check phpinfo result? Is there any chance that server blocks curl connections? how can I check that?

Comment: @heron, Checking it mate.. hold on.

Comment: if(curl_errno($ch))
                {
                    die('error:' . curl_error($ch));
                }

Comment: this returned following error: Failed to connect to (some ipv6). Network is unreachable

Comment: @heron Add this `curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);` and try again?

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger added. This time error is `error: couln't connect to host`

Comment: @heron, I am afraid your host ip is blocked from doing the requests. Did you send too many requests ? Please check your server logs for more information.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran I think it's centos server blocking outgoing connections. how can I check this?

Comment: @heron , Copy the code from this link and paste on a new file on your server and let me know the status code. Thanks. https://eval.in/132753